# Lazy load spring beans defined in the framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

In our enterprise framework, we have a list of Spring beans(`@Bean`) defined in a config(`@Configuration`) class. For some reason, we want to lazy load all the Spring beans defined in that config class but we don't have access to enterprise framework source code to add `@Lazy` to the config class.

Can someone please tell, how we can lazy load the beans defined in the framework in our application code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@ComponentScan` like this:

```
   @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ExampleController.class, ExampleModel.class, ExmapleView.class}, lazyInit = true)
```

For more info go to [link](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-auto-detection-autowire-component-scanning-example-with-annotations/)